# Python unable to terminate spawned child processes by terminating parent process

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, sigint

I have a master script (Python) from where I want to spawn several child scripts. The child scripts should run independently without bothering each other (just writing to a file in a loop). What I want - when the master script is terminated, so should all the spawned child processes.

But however, even through `CTRL-C` kills the master process and control is returned to command prompt, the child processes keep running as I can see the individual output files getting updated continually. Any idea on how to make this work?

Child script

```
import sys
from time import sleep

arg = sys.argv[1]
sleepTime = int(sys.argv[2])
while True:
    with open(f"{arg}.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(arg)
    sleep(sleepTime)
```

Master script

```
import sys, subprocess, os, signal
from time import sleep

d = ['fool', 'gool', 'lool']
for i in range(3):
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'child.py', d[i], str(i + 3)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(1)
```

What I run in command line to kick off everything:

```
python3 master.py
```

Comment: `ctrl+c` is sent to all processes connected to the terminal, and they all have a choice to ignore it, if you want to terminate abruptly then you have to catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` then forcefully `child.kill()` the children.

Comment: @AhmedAEK, thanks a lot, please explain it in code. :)

Comment: `p = Popen(...)`, then in the `KeyboardInterrupt` handler, `p.terminate()`. Your master script *knows* which processes exist and should be terminated; you just need to make use of the information.

Comment: Has tried that, did not work. I think when we keep assigning different processes to the same variable inside the loop in each iteration, it forgets the previous assignments and remembers just the latest one.

Comment: Does Ctrl-C kills the master process, really? I mean, I am sure it would if you were fast enough to type Ctrl-C before the master process ends by itself. But you are not (unless you scripted this with some keyboard fake event). The master process just spawn 3 kids and exit right away. And then those 3 kids are in background.

Comment: If you just add `sleep(30)` (or anything, but ensure your master process is still running, in foreground), then a Ctrl-C received by master process will also be received by subprocess. And they would end.

Comment: Note that it is because they also receive the ctrl-c that they end. Not because their master has died. If they were to die as soon as the master process dies, then, they would probably die before having a chance to do anything. Because before they even finish starting their own instance of python interpreter, the master has done spawning its 3 kids for long.

Comment: Your `KeyboardInterrupt` exception handler is btw, valid only during the very short time it takes the master to spawn a kid (English-wise it is quite funny to me to say master/kid rather than master/slave or parent/kid. But, well, I am not a native English speaker, and that is your naming choice, not mine :D). And each individually, one after the other. When the 3rd kid is spawn, the 3rd interrupt handler is no longer in use. Which doesn't really show, since `KeyboardInterrupt ⇒ exit` is basically the default behaviour anyway (except for interactive)

Comment: I feel that your intent was to create one interrupt handler for each kid. But that would make sense only in kid's code. It is in child.py that you could add a `KeyboardInterrupt` handler (and there also, it is not really necessary, if all you want to do to react to a KeyboardInterrupt, is exit. That is already what would happen if a child get an interrupt

Comment: Possible. Please give a complete code example explaining these suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried "just add `sleep(30)` at the end of `master.py` code? I see that I am the second person to who you reply, in substance "don't bother me with explanation, I don't want to understand, I just want you to finish my code". But I have hard time understanding how "just add `sleep(30)`" at the end of your code is not concrete enough even by that standard. Anyway, I put all that in an answer, with some codes. and explanations. And you may decide to skip the explanation part if that suits you.

Comment: Yes I can put a sleep at the end of the code, easily, in fact it is lesser to type than asking for an answer in comments, in fact. I am not doing that because I actually want to see a detailed answer explaining the nuances of this problem, there are many similar question on SO and other places without satisfactory answers, so I thought that it would be better to have an answer that explains in detail. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to terminate kids when parent terminates

Rather to continue in comments, I put this in an answer. Yet, it is still not clear to me what you are trying to do, since it is a bit contradictory, even tho, this give an answer.

The reason why it seems contradictory to me, is because you say you want the kid to terminate when the parent does. But then, your kid will have no chance to do anything at all, since the parent just spawn 3 kids (which is very fast) and then does nothing. So terminates.
The whole point of spawning subprocess is so that the parent can either do something else after the spawn, or terminate.

If you want to program the fact that the kid terminate when the parent does, you can do it that way

```
import sys, subprocess, os, signal
from time import sleep
import atexit

d = ['fool', 'gool', 'lool']
pp=[]
for i in range(3):
    try:
        p=subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'child.py', d[i], str(i + 3)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        pp.append(p)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(1)


def masterFinish():
    for p in pp:
        p.terminate()
    sys.exit(1)
atexit.register(masterFinish)
```

Or, more consistently that way

```
import sys, subprocess, os, signal
from time import sleep
import atexit

d = ['fool', 'gool', 'lool']
pp=[]
for i in range(3):
    p=subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'child.py', d[i], str(i + 3)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    pp.append(p)

def masterFinish():
    for p in pp:
        p.terminate()
    sys.exit(1)
atexit.register(masterFinish)
```

Since you don't really need that void `KeyboardInterrupt` handler, that would do something only during the very very short amount of time it takes for the parent to spawn each kid.

But, as I've said, that means that the kid are terminated as soon as the parent is. That is after the 3rd kid is spawn. In the meantime the even the 1st kids is probably still in the process of starting python interpreter, and probably had not the time to even run the first line of python code. And therefore is terminate before it had a chance to do something.

On my machine, it creates no file at all. Kid 1 is spawn, then kid 2, then kid 3, then they are all terminated and the "master" ends. And that's all. That is what you asked for, but I doubt that is what you wanted.

### How to handle Ctrl-C in kids

My feeling is that your "interruptHandler" was meant to run in background, which each of the kid, and ensure that the kid terminates when ctrl-c is received. But it doesn't work like that. The part of the code that runs in background is the one of the kids. Your handler is part of "master" code,

So where you should put your "Interrupt handler" is in `child.py` code.

```
import sys
from time import sleep

arg = sys.argv[1]
sleepTime = int(sys.argv[2])
try:
    while True:
        with open(f"{arg}.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(arg)
        sleep(sleepTime)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit(1)
```

That is probably closer to what you were trying to do.
Maybe you already tried it, and then tried something else because it was "not working".
But it was. Just, the kid needs to receive the Ctrl-C. Which it wont, since they are detached, because the master is done.

Just add anything to `master` code, and they would receive that ctrl-c

```
import sys, subprocess, os, signal
from time import sleep

d = ['fool', 'gool', 'lool']
for i in range(3):
    try:
        subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'child.py', d[i], str(i + 3)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(1)

sleep(30)
```

And then if you hit ctrl-c, the kids are exiting. And so does the master.

Note that neither the interrupt handler of the `master` nor the one of the kids are really usefull here.

- As I said earlier, the one of the master was in use only during the very short amount of times it takes to call `subprocess`. So it is over for a while before you have a chance to type ctrl-c, that would occur most probably during `sleep(30)`.
- And the one I added to the kid (to show how you were supposed to add an interrupt handler to kids: in their code, not in master's code), would work (it is the `system.exit` of that handler that will be run and exit the kid), but still wasn't necessary, since it was the default behavior anyway.

Also note, that this covers only the ctrl-c pat (it explains why your kid didn't receive the ctrl-c). With this `sleep(30)`, and therefore during the 30 seconds while `master` is still running, if you type ctrl-c, the kids will also receive it, and end.

It doesn't cover what happens after those 30 seconds.
So, need my first answer anyway (atexit — or other ways to implement the same thing. For example, just terminate the kid at the end of `master` code)

```
import sys
from time import sleep

arg = sys.argv[1]
sleepTime = int(sys.argv[2])
while True:
    with open(f"{arg}.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(arg)
    sleep(sleepTime)
```

```
import sys, subprocess, os, signal
from time import sleep

d = ['fool', 'gool', 'lool']
pp=[]
for i in range(3):
    p=subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'child.py', d[i], str(i + 3)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    pp.append(p)

sleep(30) # or do something else

for p in pp: p.terminate()
```

In this last example, with no void interrupt handler, neither in the master nor in child, both master and child would receive a ctrl-c during the 30 seconds periods while master is running with child in background. And would react to it with default behavior, that is by terminating.

Then, after the end of the 30 seconds (or whatever else master is doing while child work), master ends, and before ending, ends its child.

Comment: Now, that's some explanation! :) This is why I was pushing for an answer, so that I (and others later) can understand the nuances, this problem is far more common than we think. :)

Comment: Just curious - what happens if the process runs more than 30 seconds and then we need to terminate via CTRL-C? Essentially the child processes will need to run infinitely until we detect that many of those processes are not outputting properly or stuck somewhere, etc., in which case we want to abort the whole process (including those children which were otherwise doing fine) and restart the master (and hence all children - new ones) once again.

Comment: You can't. `master` must continue to run, otherwise, the console doesn't belong to you anymore. Once master is over, Ctrl-C are for the `bash` (or whatever) that runs it that terminal, and whatever commands that bash runs next. You have to understand how that works: SIGINT is the signal send to a process to tells that someone wants it to terminate (if it so wishes. That is up to it to decide how to react to a SIGINT. But python programs, by default, decide to end). That SIGINT doesn't appear out of nowhere. Someone has to send it to the process.

Comment: Ctrl-C is just a sequence of keys, like any other (on my terminal, it means copy, and it is shif+ctrl+c that means "send a sigint to the program that you run). So, at the beginning, it is just a classical keystroke => callback in the terminal process. And what the terminal does in reaction to the key ctrl+c is to send a SIGINT to the process it has spawned. Usually `bash`. So `bash` whose job is to `fork/exec` to run some commands, receives that SIGINT. And what it does with that is to send it to the `foreground job` (a bash notion) if it has one.

Comment: "foreground job" being for bash the process that is has forked without any `&`, that is the one that it is waiting before starting to read for command from the user again. In your case, that is `python master.py`... unless that process has ended. If that process has ended, then bash is no longer waiting for a process to end. It has returned to REP loop (read command from user, executing it, printing result). If it were to send a sigint to someone, it would be to a future other process that you may run, now that you can again type some command.

Comment: So, if you want to send SIGINT, via a ctrl+c stroke in your terminal, the only way is that `master.py` process do not end. Either because you do something like `while True: sleep(30)`. Or, probably more on point (but again, I don't really get what your are trying to do. What you said so far is a bit contradictory. You want to terminate processes when main terminates, but you also want main to terminates when it has nothing to do, and it has nothing to do... That the reason why I didn't want to answer in the first place: comments are the place where we ask for clarification on what is the

Comment: real question, and you answer once you know what is the question. Which is partly the case, or else, I wouldn't have answered, but not fully). But, well, if I surmise correctly what you are trying to do, that is spawning some subprocess and then keeping the console stuck to be able to ctrl+c all subprocess if needed, then some `os.wait()` is probably more suited than `sleep(∞)`

Comment: For example `for _ in range(len(pp)): os.wait()` would wait for all process to terminate, and then, and only then, `master` ends and your console returns to bash prompt. And in the meantime, if you type ctrl+c, all the remaining subprocess are sent a SIGINT.

Comment: Or, since you seem to exepect all `child.py` to run forever, but want to terminate everything if a single one goes south, you could even just `os.wait()` alone (instead of `sleep`). That way, `master` stays on the foregound, doing nothing, until a single one of your processes ends, in which case, master ends (and because of the `atexit` thing, asks all it other subprocesses to end before that).

Comment: But anyway, you can't just end `master.py`, return to the `bash` prompt, ready to accept other commands, and expect ctrl+c'ed bash process to continue to send signals to the now fully autonomous, in background, `child.py` process (well, not strictly speaking "background": background would be if bash was even aware that those process exist, but ran them in background with `&`. That is not even the case here. `child.py` subprocess are not related to bash, so even if it wanted to send sigint to "background" process it couldn't. But anyway it doesn't want to)

Comment: Okay, sorry for the confusion, I don't want the master to terminate, I want it to keep running (that way I can get to see the outputs of all child processes continually as they keep running), when I press `CTRL-C`, I want it to terminate and in turn terminate all child processes as well. So putting an infinite `while True` loop or `os.wait()` at the end should do it, right?

Comment: @NedStarkOfWinterfell yep.